# Material UI, TypeScript, Storybook - custom color added to Theme missing from Storybook control values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, storybook

I am using React 18, TypeScript, MUI 5 and Storybook 6.5.
I and trying to add custom colors to my MUI Theme and have them reflected in Storybook's dropdown options for my Button component's color prop but it doesn't seem to work.
I followed the instructions for module augmentation in MUI's docs and the MaterialButton component does accept "myCustomColor" when hardcoded but Storybook won't show it in the color prop's dropdown options.
I'd appreciate any pointers / ideas.

Currently my files look like this:

```
// src/styles/theme.ts
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    myCustomColor: {
      main: '#ff5555',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
  },
});
```

```
// src/styles/expanded-theme.ts
import '@mui/material/styles';
import '@mui/material/Button';

declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
    interface Palette {
        myCustomColor: Palette['primary'];
    }
    interface PaletteOptions {
        myCustomColor?: PaletteOptions['primary'];
    }
}

declare module '@mui/material/Button/Button' {
    interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
        myCustomColor: true;
    }
}
```

```
// src/components/Button.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Button as MaterialButton } from "@mui/material";
import type { ButtonProps as MuiButtonProps } from "@mui/material";

export interface ButtonProps extends MuiButtonProps {
  label: string;
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
}

export const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  const { label } = props;
  return <MaterialButton {...props}>{label}</MaterialButton>;
};
```

```
// .storybook/preview.js
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { Story } from "@storybook/react";

import { theme } from "../src/styles/theme";

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    expanded: true, // Adds the description and default columns
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};

export const withMuiTheme = (Story) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Story />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export const decorators = [withMuiTheme];
```

```
// .storybook/main.js
module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    builder: "@storybook/builder-webpack5",
  },
  typescript: {
    check: false,
    checkOptions: {},
    reactDocgen: "react-docgen-typescript",
    reactDocgenTypescriptOptions: {
      allowSyntheticDefaultImports: false, // speeds up storybook build time
      esModuleInterop: false, // speeds up storybook build time
      shouldExtractLiteralValuesFromEnum: true, // makes union prop types like variant and size appear as select controls
      shouldRemoveUndefinedFromOptional: true, // makes string and boolean types that can be undefined appear as inputs and switches
      savePropValueAsString: true,
      propFilter: (prop) => (prop.parent ? !/node_modules/.test(prop.parent.fileName) : true),
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We ended up sort of working around this by using [Storybook argTypes](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/argtypes).
This solves the problem of missing values but forces us to define them ourselves.

There's a [related issue open on Storybook's GH](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12129) repo and I posted a comment but didn't get any answer yet.

We're using the keys from the MUI Theme's Palette object and filtering out the ones we know are not actually colors:

```
import { theme } from './theme';

const paletteKeysThatAreNotColors = [
  'mode',
  'common',
  'grey', // this is not a color even though it has the name of one :shrug:
  'contrastThreshold',
  'getContrastText',
  'augmentColor',
  'tonalOffset',
  'text',
  'divider',
  'background',
  'action',
];

const colors = Object.keys(theme.palette).filter(
  (colorKey) => !paletteKeysThatAreNotColors.includes(colorKey),
);
export default colors;
```